# [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I wanted to use the Toast component from `PrimeVue` library and I also wanted to create a nice re-usable service for it but I am getting this error. This doesn't seem to be a problem if I don't try to extract a separate service for the Toast notification.

But I do want to call `useToast()` from inside my custom service and not directly in component's `setup` function.

I am using `Vue 3.2.25` with `Vite.js 2.9.9` and the latest version of `PrimeVue`

```
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <App>

Uncaught Error: No PrimeVue Toast provided!
    at useToast (usetoast.esm.js:8:15)
    at Proxy.showToast (toastService.js:4:19)
    at _createElementVNode.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (App.vue:4:21)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:369:13)
```

Here is a CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/prime-vue-toast-issue-owcio8?file=/src/services/toastService.js

Here is my **main.js**

```js
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css';
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(PrimeVue);
app.use(ToastService);

app.mount('#app')
```

And here is my **App.vue**

```
<template>
    <Toast />

    <button @click="showToast">Show toast!</button>
</template>

<script setup>
    import Toast from 'primevue/toast';
    import { showToast } from './services/toastService';
</script>
```

and here is my **toastService.js:**

```js
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

const showToast = () => {
    const toast = useToast();

    toast.add({ severity: 'info', detail:'Hello' });
}

export { showToast }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vue composables are primarily supposed to be used directly in setup function, when component instance is created. Some of them can be used in other places but this depends on the implementation of a composable and should be additionally confirmed.

The error suggests that `useToast` uses `inject` internally, this restricts the usage of this composable.

For a reusable service, it can be:

```
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";

export const useToastService = () => {
  const toast = useToast();

  const showToast = () => {
    toast.add({ severity: 'info', detail:'Hello' });
  }

  return { showToast };
};
```

And used like:

```
const { showToast } = useToastService();
```

Nothing in PrimeVue `Toast` implementation actually requires to use `useToast` composable, it's a convenience helper; see [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/3.23.0/components/usetoast/UseToast.js) and [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/3.23.0/components/toastservice/ToastService.js). With some risk of refactoring toast service on the next major library update, it could be simplified to using:

```
import ToastEventBus from 'primevue/toasteventbus';

export const useToastService = () => {
  const showToast = () => {
    ToastEventBus.emit('add', { severity: 'info', detail:'Hello' });
  }

  return { showToast };
};
```

This way the service could be used with some discretion in any place of the app, e.g. in a router.

Comment: can you explain your code why it works? I spent 1 day using ChatGPT and didn't succeed

Comment: @Mohammad The original implementation injects ToastEventBus with provide/inject that can be only used inside a component, this limitation is unnecessary in this case. The last snippet imports ToastEventBus directly without provide/inject, so it can be used in any place of the app